# Is sometimes "how I shall" = "how shall I"?

Tags: sentence-construction, exclamatives

"I shall certainly hoodwink the archbishop, and how I shall enjoy doing it!"

This is a quote known to be said by Mozart. A couple of books on him have this sentence somewhere in them.

What confuses me is the latter part of the sentence, *how I shall enjoy doing it*.

To me, neither is that grammatically right nor does it make sense to me, unless I assume that has the same meaning as *how shall I enjoy doing it*.

Or is there a different way to translate it?

Thanks.

Comment: *How I shall* is an exclamation. It is not a question. And note the sentence ends with an exclamation mark!

Comment: ... and boy am I going to enjoy doing it!   (Which I suppose is no help ...)  How about "And I am really going to enjoy doing it"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really about English.

Comment: @J.Taylor How is it NOT about English?  It's not about Latin or any other language.  It is certainly about "**_English Language** and Usage_".

Comment: @TrevorD ...This question involves a quote from a person who did not use English.

Comment: @J.Taylor You've contradicted yourself: the quote is clearly attempting to use the English language! So how can you say that it is "from a person who did not use English".  I think you may mean that his native language is/was not English - but the quote is clearly from person attempting to "use English"!!  So the Q. clearly IS "about English".  But I agree that it is probably now better placed in ELL rather than in EL&U.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"How I shall enjoy doing it!" is not a question, it is an exclamatory sentence. This kind of sentence is  used for emphasis - here it means "I will enjoy it very much!"

In questions the auxiliary verb comes before the main verb:

> "How shall I enjoy doing it?"

This could mean the person doubts that they will enjoy doing something, and is asking how they might be able to enjoy it.

In exclamatory sentences the word order is like an ordinary sentence, with auxiliary verb first and main verb second:

> How I shall enjoy doing it!
>
> What a beautiful sunset that was!

Comment: The grammar of "How I shall enjoy doing it!" is the same as "I shall enjoy doing it!" with "How" for emphasis. Then it's easy to understand it's not a question "Shall I enjoy doing it?" / "How shall I enjoy doing it?", where "how" is not used for emphasis but is part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

"How shall I" is a question, "how i shall" isn't.  The latter can mean something like, "I will really enjoy doing it". It's almost like a rhetorical question,  "how much is it that I shall enjoy doing it? Obviously a lot"

Answer (score -1):

"How I shall..." is not a common locution and I suspect this is a clumsy translation from the German.

This type of sentiment is often expressed in English with *what* ("Oh what fun we had" - Madness).

There do exist a few set expressions with *how*, e.g. "How I have longed for..."
(and not "How have I..." where inversion would imply a question being asked.)